# How to pass a returned value into another function

Tags: python

I am trying to call the list I created in a sub-function, into another sub-function. Using parameters and call functions are my Achilles heel as it relates to python. I want to call the newList I created in the calculateZscore function, into mu globalChi function.

My current code:

```
import os
import math

'''
c:/Scripts/Lab2Data
NCSIDS_ObsExp.txt
chisquare.txt
output.txt
'''
def main():
    directory = raw_input ("What is the working directory? ")    
    input_file = raw_input ("What is the name of the input file? ")    
    chiTable = raw_input ("What is the name of the chi-squared table? ")    
    outPut = raw_input ("What is the name of the output file? ")    
    path = os.path.join(directory,input_file)
    path_1 = os.path.join(directory, chiTable)
    path_2 =  os.path.join(directory, outPut)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()    

def calculateZscore(inFileName, outFileName):
    inputFile = open(inFileName,"r")  
    txtfile = open(outFileName, 'w')

for line in inputFile:
    newList = line.strip().split(',')
    obsExp = newList[-2:]
    obsExp = list(map(int, obsExp))
    obs = obsExp[0]
    exp = obsExp[1]
    zScore = (obs - exp) / math.sqrt(exp)
    zScore = map(str, [zScore])
    newList.extend(zScore)
    txtfile = open(outFileName, 'w')
    txtfile.writelines(newList) 

    inputFile.close() #close the files
    txtfile.close()
    return newList #return the list containing z scores

def globalChi(zscoreList):
print newList
```

Comment: Can you create a simpler example which illustrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: Also, your indentation appears to be off in the code you posted here. Please edit it to be the same as what you are actually running. Note that for proper formatting on this site, you must add four spaces at the beginning of every line in addition to the spaces for your actual indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about the [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) statement. It is used to make a function return a result (the opposite of taking an argument), and cannot be used outside a function.
Here, you are doing the exact opposite.